# How can I change text color on hover while using template literals?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I have the following piece of code:

```
<div
  id={id}
  className={`rounded-lg bg-background-section h-72 p-4 flex flex-col items-center relative hover:bg-background-highlight hover:text-[${color}] transition ease-in-out`}
>
  Hello there
</div>
```

I'm rendering multiple instances of that div, getting a different `color` value for each one. Thing is, the hover doesn't work **until** I manually set the color that I want in the code:

Example:

```
hover:text-[#7cc327]
```

Save, go to the browser to test it out (it works just fine).

Go back and restore the code to its original form:

```
hover:text-[${color}]
```

And now it takes the color from the variable. I ve to do the same thing for all the 9 colors that I have, but its just a waste of time cause it shouldn't work that way and also... it stops working whenever I restart the dev server.

Any idea of whats going on?

Comment: Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider using a full class names whereever `color` is declared (ensuring that this code is covered in the `content` file globs too):

```
const color = `hover:text-[#7cc327]`;
…
<div className={`… ${color} …`}>
```

Otherwise, if the color value is going to be truly dynamic or the above method cannot work for your use case, you could use the `style` attribute like:

```
<div
  className={`… hover:text-[color:--color] …`}
  style={{ '--color': color }}
>
```